# WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-4.1.0) - How to set a management hostname different from the hostname?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and I'm trying to set a management hostname and a hostname which are different from each other. In the documentation, there's no separation and only the hostname could be set in deployment.toml which sets both the hostname and the management hostname to the set value inside carbon.xml.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/

This was possible in the older versions.
Is it possible to achieve this in the newer version?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to use a separate hostname to login to the publisher, devportal and the carbon console and another to be used for authentication purposes calling /oauth2/token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the URL by login into the /admin portal and changing the "Display Token Endpoint"

[image]

**Update**
To answer the original question you can set the following configs in the `deployment.toml` to set the HostName and Management hostname.

```ini
[server]
hostname = "{hostname}"
mgt_console_hostname = "MGT_HOST"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible to set this in deployment.toml?

Comment: @LilanMihiranga AFAIK you can't set this from deployment toml. I updated the answer to address your original question. Try that and see if it resolves the issue.